# How create a border in my OptionMenu in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

In my app created by tkinter, an `optionmenu` appears and I wanted to detach it with a border.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
toplvl = Toplevel()
var = StringVar(root)
var.set("one")
option = ttk.OptionMenu(toplvl,var,"one","two","three",)
option.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: plz add some more info are you facing any error ? if yes then add those errors in your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make border around ttk.OptionMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534878/how-to-make-border-around-ttk-optionmenu)